# A problem of proving strong convergent sub-sequence in infinite Hilbert space

Tags: functional-analysis, hilbert-spaces

H is an infinite Hilbert space. Get

$$\left\{ \begin{array}{l}
\begin{array}{*{20}{l}}
{\left\| {{a_n} + {b_n}} \right\| \to \left\| c \right\|}\\
{{a_n} \to a}\\
{{b_n} \rightharpoonup b}
\end{array}\\
\left\| {{b_n}} \right\| \le C\left\| {{a_n} + {b_n}} \right\|
\end{array} \right.$$

$C$ is a positive constant. The symbol of full and half arrows are strong and weak convergence. I need to prove that there exists a subsequence of $\left\{ {{b_n}} \right\}$ such that it strongly converges to $b$, i.e  ${b_{{n_k}}} \to b,k \to \infty $.

I guess that it is not true, but I haven't got any counter-examples.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$a_n$ can just be identically zero, in which case you're asking for $b_n$ converging weakly and with converging norms to have a strongly convergent subsequence. There are numerous counterexamples to that, e.g. $b_n=\sin(nx)$ in $L^2[0,\pi]$.

Comment: Sorry, I need to add that all sequences are non-zero.

Comment: @NguyenDangSon Doesn't matter, something like $a_n=1,b_n=\cos(nx)$ on $L^2[0,\pi]$ does the job just as well.

Comment: I see your mean. I mean that $a_n$ is not trivial sequence like constant sequence. However, from your idea, we may create a counter-example. Thanks.

Comment: @NguyenDangSon The point is that your first last conditions provide only very weak coupling between $a_n$ and $b_n$. You're going to need a stronger relationship to get strong convergence of $b_n$. Indeed really any pair of sequences with $a_n$ converging strongly, $b_n$ converging weakly but not strongly, $b_n$ bounded, and $a_n \perp b_n$ will do in this situation.

Comment: I see. I am finding some the weakest conditions to obtain strong convergence of sub-sequence $b_n$.

Comment: You added the condition ${a_n} \bot {b_n}$, but I cannot prove that $b_n$ strongly converges. How do you do?

Comment: I meant that with the orthogonality condition you can ensure that the first and fourth conditions hold without allowing $b_n$ to strongly converge.